# Como remover o primeiro elemento de um array no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de saber como remover o primeiro elemento de um array.

```js
//Array atual:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

//Como quero que fique:
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Tenta usar ```array.shift()```. Isso vai remover o primeiro elemento.

Answer (score 2):

O método `shift()` remove o primeiro elemento de um array e retorna esse elemento. Este método muda o tamanho do array.

exemplo:

```js
const compras = ['café', 'banana', 'queijo']
compras.shift()
console.log(compras) //["banana", "queijo"]
```

Para saber mais veja em

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift